# Spring MVC + JSF: Form URLs wrong

Tags: forms, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I try to use Spring MVC with JSF. But I use JSF just as presentation layer. Its not a problem to display a JSF view for my `@Controller`... but if I use a `h:form`, the renderer uses a wrong URL (without my dispatcher).

This is the correct URL to get the view (method=GET):
`http://localhost:8080/AppName/dispatcher/testController/create`

The JSF views form gets rendered with this URL:
`http://localhost:8080/AppName/WEB-INF/jsf/testController/create`

The correct URL for the form would be (method=POST):
`http://localhost:8080/AppName/dispatcher/testController/create`

**My Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/testController")
public final class TestController
{

  [...]

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void getCreateNew(final Model model)
  {
    [...]
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void postCreateNew(final Model model)
  {
    [...]
  }
}
```

**My View:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:l="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     >

    <h:head>
        <title>Create new</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:messages errorClass="error"/> 

        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">
                    <h:outputText value="${name}" />
                    <p:inputText label="Test: ${name}" required="true">
                        <f:validateLength minimum="3" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton type="submit" value="${labelSubmit}" action="spring:@testController.doneCreateNew" />
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**The web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**The faces-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

**The dispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsf/" p:suffix=".jsf" />

</beans>
```

**And the applicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sommer_engineering"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>

</beans>
```

Anybody knows why this does not work? I would be happy for any idea...

Comment: In first place, why the heck are you trying to mix two competing MVC frameworks with each a completely different ideology (request based MVC versus component based MVC)? Just choose the one or the other. If you used JSF for the sole reason because its view technology Facelets is so much more awesome than JSP, then you should use Facelets + SWF instead, or just drop Spring MVC altogether. If you sole reason is to have pretty URLs, look at PrettyFaces instead, or just drop JSF altogether.

Comment: @BalusC: Hmmm... thanks for your response. Yes, you are right: I wanted JSF just for using the pretty PrimeFaces. I have made my thougth! For many things, Spring + JSP + e.g. Twitter Bootstrap would be just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**see edit below**

I'll leave my answer here since I had to work through this same issue myself.  Integrating a rewrite rule through a simple pretty-config worked for me.

1. Add the dependencies for [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) 
   (note: If you're not familiar with PrettyFaces, then it's probably not what you think it is)
2. Add the rewrite rule

if your servlet mapping for the dispatcher looks like:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/dispatcher/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and your view resolver has properties like this:

```
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsf/" p:suffix=".jsf"
```

then your pretty-config.xml should be something like:

```
     <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                  http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

        <url-mapping id="pretty_spring_urls">
            <pattern value="/dispatcher/WEB-INF/jsf/{spring}.jsf" />
            <view-id value="/dispatcher/{spring}" />
        </url-mapping>

    </pretty-config>
```

**edit:**
Prettyfaces, however, has only worked for me on an embedded glassfish server.  [Urlrewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) has worked for me on glassfish, tomcat 7 and jboss.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to imply it to dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="" p:suffix=".jsf" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. If I understand it correct, I then must provide all my JSF views directly accessable before WEB-INF. If I just add your idea additional to the existing rules, it does not work as well.